# Microsoft Access - not using a validation code

Tags: validation, ms-access, rules

Under `PostCode`, I've put an input mask as well as a validation rule of '`Is Not Null`'
[image: Valdiation rules]
The input mask is working fine. However, the validation rule isn't working as it allows the postcode to be null.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Options I can see:

1. `Nz([Postcode],"")<>""`
2. set field as required in table and let Access nag users
3. validation code in BeforeUpdate event of control and form